# uploadify 3 - email after upload with filename

Tags: php, email, uploadify, uploadifive

I would like to have uploadify sending me an email after upload is done.

with uploadify 2.14 I used:

```
    $empfaenger = "upload@myemail.com";
    $betreff = "TEST: Upload eines Files";
    $from = "From: $empfaenger";
    $text = "TEST: Ein File mit dem Namen '$filename'  wurde hochgeladen ";
    mail($empfaenger, $betreff, $text, $from);
```

it worked well, but with uploadify 3.2.1 it is not working 100% - I got an email but the filename is mising! how can I get the uploaded file's name into that email?
would be grat if the code would work also with uplodifive as well as I would like to purchase that version.

Any ideas?

Comment: you didn't put file name in email?

Comment: solution was found :)

 $text = "TEST: Ein File mit dem Namen '".$_FILES['Filedata']['name']."' wurde hochgeladen ";

Comment: What is the solution ?